# How to overcome strange overflow lag in tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've this sample of a page where I struggle to find why, when resizing to lower widths, an horizontal overflow of the top navigation bar happens late letting the whole page go into horizontal overflow as well(which doesn't happen on other pages where such navigation bar is not present):

[image]

The test playground:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/wnjrcilDBX

Does anybody have an explanation of what's wrong?

Comment: Your navigation bar isn't the only thing that is too wide.  Look at the lower right hand corner of your page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey sorry, I can't see it

Comment: It is the area containing the text "Elimina Salva i periodi" that is overflowing, not your navigation bar.

Comment: nope, that's within another component that scales correctly if you remove the top navigation bar(try it by removing from the father div of the h2 "Cronometro allenamenti HIIT")

Comment: So, how does Tailwind (i.e. CSS) know which element you want to scale first?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the top navbar first, I expected that once there's no more space for the items it will overflow given the setup, and indeed it does overflow at first showing the scrollbar, but then when the `width` gets smaller it stops from overflowing proportionally correctly and makes the rest of elements compress instead.

Comment: Here is my suggestion: *avoid horizontal scroll bars."  They generally are a poor user experience, and I don't think you're going to easily get what you want with them here.  I suggest pursuing a different layout that doesn't require horizontal scrollbars.  A vertical accordion, perhaps?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed yesterday I endend up with a `flex-nowrap` solution, so the elements go to a new row automatically, but this works for the desktop media, on mobile I still resort to make it overflow and strangely enough, is does overflow correctly there(probably because I think the layout is more of a column than a row).

Despite this vertical accordions take too much space on mobile for a web-app that covers the whole screen with no overflows at the page level. Is there any better secondary navigation bar on mobile that can be better in terms of UI and UX?